# Pass a boolean to a view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

**What I try to do:**

I try to pass a boolean to my view to to check if it is true or not. If it is set to true, I want to add a class. I use Laravel. Actually, here is my situation:

- The .red class is added to all rows
- $finances->depense always return 1 even if it says 0 in the database

Here is my code:

**index.blade.php**

```
@foreach($finances as $finance)
    @if ($finance->depense = 1)
        <tr class="red">
    @elseif ($finance->depense = 0) 
        <tr>
    @endif
            <td><a href="{{ URL::to('finances/' . $finance->id) }}">{{$finance->description}}</a></td>
            <td>{{ $finance->depense }}</td>
            <td>{{ $finance->prix }}</td>
            <td>{{ $finance->tps }}</td>
            <td>{{ $finance->tvq }}</td>
            <td>{{ $finance->grandtotal }}</td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

FinancesController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $finances = Finance::all();
    return View::make('finances.index')->withFinances($finances);
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: = is for assignment, not for comparison. That's why you always get 1. Use == instead.

Comment: @Carter Yes thank you I just realized!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was finally very simple..

Instead of

```
@if ($finance->depense = 1)
    <tr class="red">
@elseif ($finance->depense = 0) 
    <tr>
@endif
```

I changed the expression from **`=`** *(Assignment Operator)* to **`==`** *(Equal)*

```
@if ($finance->depense == 1)
    <tr class="red">
@else 
    <tr>
@endif
```

Don't forget to use double equal to compare.

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong but I thought you don't need to do comparison with boolean value for a condition check, as it defaults to true.

```
@if ($finance->depense)
    <tr class="red">
@else 
    <tr>
@endif
```

If you want to check for false add the '!'

```
@if (!$finance->depense)
    <tr class="red">
@else 
    <tr>
@endif
```

Comment: Correct you are